# Gran problema con PHPMailer, no consigo que envie correos [adjunto error]

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy ejecutando un script que envía correos, pero no consigo que funcione.

Este es mi código. ¿Alguna observación?:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.serviciodecorreo.es';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'admin@*****.**';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('admin@*****.**');
$mail->addAddress('******@**.com');     // Add a recipient



//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

He cambiado el debug al valor 3 y esto es lo que me sale. ¿álguien sabe que ocurre?

```
2018-02-23 09:05:56 Connection: opening to 
ssl://smtp.serviciodecorreo.es:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-02-23 09:05:56 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL 
operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed 
[C:\inetpub\SIADE\PHPMAIL\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 325]
2018-02-23 09:05:56 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): 
Failed to enable crypto 
[C:\inetpub\SIADE\PHPMAIL\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 325]
2018-02-23 09:05:56 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): 
unable to connect to ssl://smtp.serviciodecorreo.es:465 (Unknown error) 
[C:\inetpub\SIADE\PHPMAIL\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 325]
2018-02-23 09:05:56 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

¿Tendrá algo que ver con la configuración del IIS?

Comment: Para que puedas enviar un email con php mailer asegurate de haber dado acceso al cliente de correo que utilizas para que pueda enviar desde aplicacionies externas. Te puedo invitar a que leas la siguiente lectura que encontré: [phpmailer](https://www.comalis.com/ayuda/envio-correos-php-smtp-phpmailer)
También te invito a que le des una leída a la documentación [oficial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: podrías mostrar el error que te muestra el programa? para analizar si es un problema de transporte, armado de email, entre otros.
Asegúrate de estar en modo debug para que muestre la mayor cantidad posible de información

Comment: Listo Carlos, he añadido el error que me sale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.6 introduce la verificación del certificado SSL. Es lo mismo que un certificado SSL para un servidor web: debe coincidir con el dominio, debe estar firmado por una CA confiable y debe tener un hash SHA2 y una clave de 2048 bits. Si no quieres reconfigurar tu servidor, es posible forzar a tu script para que vuelva al comportamiento anterior a la verificación de los certificados, es decir, decirle que no verifique el certificado. De este modo, dejarás de obtener error por certificado incorrecto

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true ));
```

Comment: En la configuración del correo, pone que para utilizar el servidor smtp, requiere ssl y ese puerto.

Comment: PHP 5.6 introduces SSL certificate verification, so if your config is broken, it will fail with this error. You should fix your SSL, but you can revert to the old behaviour by setting the SMTPOptions property to not verify certificates:

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
));

Comment: GUAU! Ha funcionado Sergio! Podrías modificar la respuesta y explicar el funcionamiento y el por qué? Estaré encantado de marcarla como útil y correcta.

Comment: No me deja modificarla, así que te la pongo la explicación del código. ;)     PHP 5.6 introduce la verificación del certificado SSL. Es lo mismo que un certificado SSL para un servidor web: debe coincidir con el dominio, debe estar firmado por una CA confiable y debe tener un hash SHA2 y una clave de 2048 bits. Si no quieres reconfigurar tu servidor, es posible forzar a tu script para que vuelva al comportamiento anterior a la verificación de los certificados, es decir, decirle que no verifique el certificado. De este modo, dejarás de obtener error por certificado incorrecto.

Comment: Muy buena ayuda me sirvio al 100% gracias por tu colaboacion